Can not run db.fsyncLock() in a MongoDB Atlas cluster
I've deployed a MongoDB sharded cluster in MongoDB Atlas dedicated. For some reason i am trying to run db.fsyncLock() from a secondary. But It's giving me unauthorized error. I also tried many command like findAndModify a collection in config database, but same error. Though I give so many privilege to my user through Atlas UI.
My user has these roles:
authenticatedUserRoles: [
  { role: 'atlasAdmin', db: 'admin' },
  { role: 'backup', db: 'admin' },
  { role: 'clusterMonitor', db: 'admin' },
  { role: 'dbAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' },
  { role: 'enableSharding', db: 'admin' },
  { role: 'readWriteAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' }
]

I am getting this error:

MongoServerError[Unauthorized]: not authorized on admin to execute command { fsync: 1, lock: true, lsid: { id: UUID("3c98878b-9c36-4a5a-945f-f844bda6c04f") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1726470174, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, D048A6DCF75FA7B59DB4AE831656E536D1ED989A), keyId: 7415097913686097942 } }, $readPreference: { mode: "primaryPreferred" }, $db: "admin" }

Is there any to run these kind of command from Atlas managed MongoDB cluster?

This command is not supported in Atlas, see Unsupported Commands in Atlas What is "some reason" why you try to execute it?

Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit. We were trying to bring a generic database backup solution with restic. So that this command was needed.

Why do you not use the build-in standard backup solution in Atlas? You have no direct access to the file system anyway.
